# Global tree structure in Android

Tags: android, data-structures

I am making an app for Android which is based on a big tree structure in which I need to change the values of the nodes. Basically the structure is:

```
private class Node {
    Fields;
    List of child nodes;
}
```

I need to alter the value of the fields in different activities, so I need to be able to see my structure from most of my activities. My first thought was to implement this as a class, make my tree and pass the tree from activity to activity. But having read up on this, it does not seem to be a good (possible?) idea. Obviously I need to be able to both get and set all the fields of all the nodes.

Besides this tree I need another structure consisting of complex types (classes) which needs to be just as visible as the tree.

I will create the structures on startup, reading the values from a file.

Can anyone tell me how I can accomplish this?

Thanks in advance,

LordJesus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend the `Application` class and put your central data in there. It is created on app startup and available to all activities (using `getApplication()`).

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html